# Couchbase failed to start

Tags: couchbase

> Failed to load NIF library
>   /opt/couchbase-server/couchbase/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.2/priv/lib/crypto:
>   'libcrypto.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory'" OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.
>   [error_logger:error,2015-09-01T22:14:20.025,nonode@nohost:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:do_log:203]The
>   on_load function for module crypto returned {error,
>   load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library
>   /opt/couchbase-server/couchbase/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-3.2/priv/lib/crypto:
>   'libcrypto.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory'"}}

Comment: The machine is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this thread: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/dependency-libcrypto-so-6-fail/31/5

which suggest you do this:
    yum install openssl098e